# What is the name of the middle matrix in a quadratic form $x'Ax$?

Tags: terminology, quadratic-forms, hessian-matrix

In a quadratic form, $x'Ax$, does matrix $A$ have a special name? I am trying to write a sentence that looks like "Using vector $x$ and matrix $A$ as the ______ matrix, we can write the quadratic form as $x'Ax$...". I don't know if "multiplicand" or something similar is used to describe this matrix.

Comment: I would call it "matrix associated with the quadratic form".

Comment: By $x'$ you mean transpose, right?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't write "Using vector $x$ and matrix $A$..." as it seems to imply that $x$ is a fixed vector, while in reality you want to say that any quadratic form can be written as map $x\mapsto x'Ax$ for some fixed matrix $A$.